# Get HH:MM:SS from a datetime in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, format

I have the following issue:

I have a datetime field, which contains entries like this: "1970-01-01 22:09:26.000"

I would like to extract only the 22:09:26 (hh:mm:ss) part, but I am unable to convert it into 24h format, I used FORMAT and CONVERT, but received the the am/pm culture (for the CONVERT I tried to use 13 culture value).

What is the simplest way to construct the formula to give back the above mentioned format?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you displaying this data?  This kind of formatting is normally something that would be handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: Why not just `CONVERT` your data to a `time` (`time(0)` as you don't want any milliseconds) as you're just after the time portion?

Comment: Point to note on `format` and `time(0)` is that `format` won't round your seconds whereas `time(0)` will.  A `time` value of `12:00:12.7566667` will output `12:00:13` when converted to `time(0)` but `12:00:12` when using `format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st way
You can select the format you wish from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

```
select replace(convert(nvarchar(20), CAST('1970-01-01 22:09:26.000' AS datetime), 114),'-',':')
```

2nd way
It is not a conversion,but if your entries are all the same format then you can use the below:

```
select right('1970-01-01 22:09:26.000',12)
```

Updated if you have null dates as well:

1.

```
select case when value is not null
        then replace(convert(nvarchar(20), CAST(value AS datetime), 114),'-',':')
            else null
       end
```

2. 

```
select case when value is not null then right(value,12)
     else null end
```

Comment: Sadly, they are not working since I have NULLs: 

in the first case I got results with milliseconds and in the second case due to the AM/PM en-us culture I got results like this: 1970  2:12AM

Comment: when it is null,you want to let it null?

Answer (score 1):

To get just the `time` portion of a `datetime` you just need to `cast` or `convert` it into the appropriate data type.  If you *really* want to be formatting your data right in the query, this is very possible with `format` and I am not sure what issues you were facing there:

```
declare @t table(d datetime);
insert into @t values(dateadd(minute,-90,getdate())),(dateadd(minute,-60,getdate())),(dateadd(minute,-30,getdate())),(dateadd(minute,90,getdate()));

select d
      ,cast(d as time) as TimeValue
      ,format(d,'HH:mm:ss') as FormattedTimeValue
from @t;
```

### Output

```
+-------------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|            d            |    TimeValue     | FormattedTimeValue |
+-------------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 2020-08-10 11:51:15.560 | 11:51:15.5600000 | 11:51:15           |
| 2020-08-10 12:21:15.560 | 12:21:15.5600000 | 12:21:15           |
| 2020-08-10 12:51:15.560 | 12:51:15.5600000 | 12:51:15           |
| 2020-08-10 14:51:15.560 | 14:51:15.5600000 | 14:51:15           |
+-------------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, 

I checked the source and in the "Main_table" the "datetimefield" is in datettime type, my problem is that when I am using the following formulas my result will be: 

SELECT
datetimefield as d,
FORMAT(datetimefield,'hh:mm:ss') as dFORMAT,
CAST([datetimefield as time) as dCAST,
CONVERT(time,datetimefield) as dCONVERT
from Main_table with (nolock)

d -> 1970-01-01 22:09:26.000
dFORMAT -> 10:09:26
dCAST -> 22:09:26.0000000
dCONVERT -> 22:09:26.0000000

Comment: @mpataki You should read up on how the `format` options work.  `hh` is 12-hour format and `HH` is 24-hour format.  Because you have used `hh` you are getting `10` instead of `22`.  Use `HH` instead.

Answer (score 1):

By using format code as 108 we can get datetime in 'HH:mm:ss' format.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @now, 108)
```